# Meteor.logout property removes email field?

Tags: meteor

I made a small application that uses:

```
meteor add accounts-base
meteor add accounts-password
```

i can register a new user with username, email and pass fields but when I logout, meteor delete the email field. why ? .

My code to register new users :

....

```
 var user=template.find('#regnombre').value;
 var email=template.find('#regemail').value;
 var pass1=template.find('#regpass1').value;
 var pass2=template.find('#regpass2').value;

 var userObject = {
  username: user,
  email: email,
  password: pass1
};

Accounts.createUser(userObject, function (err) {
```

...

My code to logout :

```
Template.logout.events({
 "submit #logout-form":function(event,template){
   Meteor.logout(function(){
     event.preventDefault();
     Modal.hide(template);
   });
 }
});
```

Comment: You mean that the email field in MongoDB is gone after logout? And are you able to login again with that particular user?

Comment: Are you looking on the client or the server? There's no way the emails key is going to be removed from the user on the server. After logout the `Meteor.user()` object will become `undefined` so by definition `Meteor.user().emails` will error.

Comment: its all in client and the email field disappears